# Msg 823, Level 24, State 2 for Clustered Column Store Index in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, columnstore

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_TempTable1 ON dbo.TempTable1 ON[PRIMARY]
```

After firing this query I found the error.

```
Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 20
The operating system returned error 1(Incorrect function.) to SQL Server during a read at 
offset 0x0000018dc18000 in file 'D:\SQL2014\Data\TempDB.MDF'. Additional messages in the 
SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe 
system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected 
immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be 
caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps in [KB2015755: How to troubleshoot a Msg 823 error in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015755). Message 823 usually indicates a hardware problem:

> The 823 error message usually indicates that there is a problem with underlying storage system or the hardware or a driver that is in the path of the I/O request. You can encounter this error when there are inconsistencies in the file system or if the database file is damaged.

The typical approach is to use SQLIOSIM to stress the IO subsystem and see if errors occur, see [KB231619: How to use the SQLIOSim utility to simulate SQL Server activity on a disk subsystem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231619).

If the stress does not report errors but the statement continues to consistently reproduce the issue then you should [contact product support](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support).

Comment: I run SQLIOSim utility, x64-based utility but still facing the same problem.

Comment: @Musakkhir Your statement is confusing. Does running SQLIOSim trigger the error, or not?

Comment: You should run it for *days* to stress the IO.

Comment: Some duplication with http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72816/create-failed-for-index-clusteredcolumnstoreindex-timeout-expired/72837#72837